# nodejs safest path and file handling

Tags: javascript, node.js, path

what security measures need to be taken when there's file access involved from client.

For instance they could use `../` to get access to root directory while we have `path` related functions involved.

What's the safest way to write path related code?

Comment: sanitize filename module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/sanitize-filename

Comment: thanks @jfriend00, what about directory traversal

Comment: That sanitize module prevents all directory traversal.  If you want to allow some directory traversal, then have to specify in your question exactly what is allowed.  Your question as it is now is not very specific about exactly what you want to allow and what you want to prevent so no precise answer is possible because the question is vague and non-specific (and thus perhaps why you got a couple downvotes).  You could fix the question to contain a mini-specification for what you're really trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) First check Poison Null bytes

```
if (filename.indexOf('\0') !== -1) {
  return respond('That was evil.');
}
```

2) Whitelisting

```
if (!/^[a-z0-9]+$/.test(filename)) {
  return respond('illegal character');
}
```

3) Preventing Directory Traversal

```
var rootDirectory = '/var/www/';

var path = require('path');
var filename = path.join(rootDirectory, userSuppliedFilename);
if (filename.indexOf(rootDirectory) !== 0) {
  return respond('trying to sneak out of the web root?');
}
```

[Reference](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/file-system/security/introduction/):